# Split database index and table files with SSD?

Tags: hard-drive, performance, ssd, database, performance-tuning

I know in the good old days it was recommended that indexs and tables were placed on different drives to improve database performance. Is this still the case with SSDs when connected with SATA3? With seek time being much less of an issue I'd imagine the performance hit is less dramatic.

I've got a 350GB (and growing) database that I'm moving to a new machine, however, the machine only has 2x SATA3 connectors. The OS and applications are going on an HDD, with purely the DB on the SSD.

Do I use 3 drives, with the OS HDD connected to an SATA2 port, and 2x 256GN SSDs on the 3 SATA3 ports, or do I use 2 drives, with the OS HDD and a 512GB SSD both on the SATA3 ports.

Advice please.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the amount of traffic you are expecting.  I've got much larger DBs with tables and indexes on the same drive simply because the disk performance is not the bottleneck, but rather users and their locking transactions.

In general though, that guidance is outdated.

Comment: It's only ever in use by a single 'user' - The data is used for mining and research.